# Problems with widget in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to make a very simple widget there. It seems to be somehow unregistered WidgetProvider, because no debug messages come to my LogCat (I'm sure, log filter is right, and I tried adding Toast show), as well as no errors come out.

I will be **really glad** of any help, because I spend few hours and tried few lessons...

I have done everything by a lesson, but changed the names and classes. There are my classes:

Provider:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


private static final String LOGIN_CLICKED = "com.example.intent.action.LOGIN_CLICKED";


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.d("my_log", "onUpdate");

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_login, buildButtonPendingIntent(context, LOGIN_CLICKED));

    pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
}

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Log.d("my_log", "buildButtonPendingIntent");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);     
}

 }
```

Receiver:

```
public class WidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String LOGIN_CLICKED = "com.example.intent.action.LOGIN_CLICKED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("my_log", "onRecieve");

    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(LOGIN_CLICKED)){
        makeLogin(context);
    }
}

private void makeLogin(Context context) {

    Log.d("my_log", "MakeLogin");

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    //remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());

    //REMEMBER TO ALWAYS REFRESH YOUR BUTTON CLICK LISTENERS!!!
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_login, WidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context, LOGIN_CLICKED));

    WidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
}
```

}

My manifest:

```
 <application
    android:label="TwiWi Twitter Widget">

    <receiver
        android:name="WidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="WidgetReceiver"
        android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.intent.action.LOGIN_CLICKED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />

    </receiver>

</application>
```

And my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dip"
    android:minHeight="146dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main" >


</appwidget-provider>
```

If you think I messed with layout or button name, there is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_textview"
                android:text="Hello Widget"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try reinstall the application.

Comment: @Nadeem lqbal tried many times..

Comment: TRY Restart the phone and reinstall application

Comment: @NadeemIqbal, restarted the phone, uninstalled the app, cleaned the project, installed - no effect.

Comment: @NadeemIqbal maybe it happends because smth wrong with action?

<action android:name="com.example.intent.action.LOGIN_CLICKED" />

I mean this one. Although, it would have updated at least once then... it's weird. Or maybe smth wrong with package? App's package is "com.example.TwiWi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Still, this Example can be full exaple of simple widget for someone, nothing wrong with it.

Lol, as always, just RESTART the Eclipse...

Comment: Oh Shit! I just missed to say RESTART ECLIPSE :D